# How to write and display comments for specific products?

Tags: php, mysql

i am doing my graduation project e-commerce website http://www.fieldhockey-world.co.uk
and i want every user to be able to comment different products and to display the comments for the specific product not displaying all comments at once. 
So far my comment code is :

```
 <?php
    include("storescripts/init.php"); //contains DB connect and functions


    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $submit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit']);


    if (logged_in() == true)      check ($SESSION['user_id'])
    {

    if ($submit){
        if ($comment)
        {$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comments` (comment, username, id) VALUES ('$comment', '$username', '$id')");
        $errors[] = 'You successfully posted a comment!';

        }
        else
        {
            $errors[] = '<span style="color:red;">Please write a comment first!</span>';
        }

        }
    }else
    {$errors[] = '<span style="color:red;">You must log in to post a comment!</span>';

    }
    ?>

    </h4>


    <table width="400" border="0" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">

      <tr>
        <td>

    <?php echo output_errors($errors) ?>       //function to output the errors

        <?php 
        $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY comment_id DESC");
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($getquery))
        {
        $username =$rows['username'];
        $comment_id = $rows['comment_id'];
        $comment = $rows['comment'];
        $date = $rows['date'];
        $id = $rows['id'];

         echo '<br>From : '. $username . '&nbsp;' . $date . '<br /><br /><em>' . $comment . '</em><hr>';


        }
        ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
    <h4>Write a comment:</h4>

    From:<br>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user_date['username']?>" size="15" name="username" readonly><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="1" />
    <textarea  name="comment" cols="35" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea><br>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" style=" background-color:orange; font-size:17px;  border-radius:10px;" value="Post">
    </form>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

my MySQL table is:

Tabel Comments

comment_id    int /
comment       text /
username      varchar/
date          timestamp

If you have any ideas please let me know.
Thanks indeed!!

Comment: add another field, product_id, so you can link them both

Comment: Note that you're using a deprecated API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a product ID key in the comments table, and create a relation for that key to the products table ID-field. Then only load comemnts matching the product ID the user is watching.

**EDIT**

Also, you should migrate away from native mysql functions to mysqli instead.
[PHP.net about Mysqli](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer very useful!! Just i dont know how to write the if statement to check do the ids match.
If (something)
{
echo "the comments";
}else{
echo "";
}
???

Comment: @Bobby ``SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `product_id` = whatever ORDER BY comment_id DESC``

You merely use the `WHERE` clause to have the database only subtract items if X matches X. In this case, if product ID matches the product ID the user is watching.

I want to re-iterate the importance of you switching away from the deprecated `mysql` functions and to `mysqli` instead.

Comment: @Bobby Glad to help! Good luck with the graduation :)

Comment: @Bobby Oh, and please mark is as the correct answer if there's nothing else.